# Book named "Someone"'s War, in which complex technology is outlawed with religious fervor

Tags: story-identification, books, military-sf

I've been racking my brain all week trying to remember the name of this book so I can go back and finish it. It's been almost a decade, so I may remember some of the details wrong.

The setting seems to be in a future version of Earth where complex technology is outlawed with religious fervor. It hints at a near apocalyptic event that brought this about, but I didn't learn the details. The technology level is roughly early industrial. The vibe is almost steampunk vibe mixed with American military tradition and British aristocracy.

The book starts off with the main character in military school, eventually being deployed to Australia, I think. It talks a lot about his correspondence with his girlfriend through letters, and I think I remember something about a campaign in India.

The "someone"'s name is a male name that feels familiar because it's also the name of a prominent historical figure, and is the name of the main character's friend/rival at the beginning of the book.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Thank you for taking the [tour], if you need to please do read the [help] for articles on voting and how accepting answers works, If you have any more details, please do [edit] them in, especially if anything in [tag:story-identification] triggers a memory. Share and Enjoy!

Comment: I've looked at the blurbs of: Oldman's War, Astrid's War, Leviathan's War, Chaplain's War, God's War and Philosopher's War... none of them seem to fit. Let me know if they do however, and somebody can post an answer.

Comment: Hmm, premise is similar to the Safehold series, but that doesn't take place on Earth and you start by learning exactly why the limitations are in place.

Comment: Butlerian Jihad? It's a bit of a trope but the key technology is often computer intelligence of some sort.

Comment: I'm actually rereading Butlerian Jihad right now! All of the books in the Dune series are so good.

Comment: Have added an answer below.  I found the book to be an enjoyable read.  If you like this one I might also recommend "Two Georges" by Harry Turtledove & Richard Dreyfuss  as well as "Peshawar Lancers" by S.M. Stirling.  Both are standalone novels that, to me at least, have similar tone.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe you are seeking the 2004 book [Fitzpatrick's War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitzpatrick%27s_War) by Theodore Judson. It was first published by Daw Books.

Points that match:

> Book named "Someone"'s War.

Yep.

> The setting seems to be in a future version of Earth

Match. 25th century Earth

> which complex technology is outlawed with religious fervor

Partial Match.  It is not so much just religious, but an electrical damping field that is preventing technology use. "At the same time the Timermen, their hidden technological elite, began developing means of rendering their enemies' electronic technology unusable through development of portable electromagnetic pulse generation technology."

> The book starts off with the main character in military school, eventually being deployed to Australia, I think.

Match. "The novel takes the form of an autobiography by a twenty-fifth century soldier, Brigadier General Sir Robert Mayfair Bruce, of the Yukon Confederacy,  The history of Judson's world is revealed in the form of an oral history exam given to **cadets at the Yukon War College,**  While a **student at the Yukon War College**, Sir Robert Mayfair Bruce, ......"

> eventually being deployed to Australia, I

Partial Match.  Not a deployment. But does end up in Australia.  "Bruce **flees with a few survivors for Australia**, where he is met by Dr. Murrey."

> The "someone"'s name is a male name that feels familiar because it's also the name of a prominent historical figure, and is the name of the main character's friend/rival at the beginning of the book.

Match and Match:  "Bruce's **story chronicles** (and criticizes) the career of **Lord Isaac Prophet Fitzpatrick**, a consul of the fictional Yukon Confederacy whose life closely parallels that of Alexander the Great."

"While a student at the Yukon War College, Sir Robert Mayfair Bruce, decorated veteran of the Mexican War of 2412, is selected by Isaac Prophet Fitzpatrick (Fitzpatrick the Younger) to join his inner circle."

Comment: Great answer! Well found and we'll explained

Comment: I find it confusing that you are using quote formatting for things that aren't quotes.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I was simply using quotes to delineate portions of text I copied in from the Wikipedia link to distinguish them from comments I was making myself.

Comment: The quoteblock was around the wrong way; you are not quoting yourself, and only some of the quoted text is copied from elsewhere, but it is already delineated by quotation marks. The text of the question is what should be quoteblocked, see edit suggestion.

Comment: prominent historical figure - should be Isaac Newton right?